# Write xml file using lxml library in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html) to create an XML file from scratch;
having a code like this:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("root")
root.set("interesting", "somewhat")
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, "test")
```

How do I write root `Element` object to an xml file using `write()` method of `ElementTree` class?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can get a string from the element and then write that from [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

```
str = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

Look at the tostring documentation to set the encoding - this was written in Python 2, Python 3 gives a binary string back which can be written directly to file but is probably not what you want in code.

or convert to an element tree (originally write to a file handle but either missed when I wrote this or it is new it can be a file name as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009021/151019) )

```
et = etree.ElementTree(root)
et.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: And `write` also accepts argument `pretty_print=True` http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: when you write `str`, make sure you write in binary mode `b`: `with open('pretty.html', 'wb') as file: file.write(str)`

Comment: As of python3, you need to use `sys.stdout.buffer` instead of `sys.stdout` - which essentially is the same as what @laviex pointed out, only for the special case of `sys.stdout`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It doesn't write to a file as requested.

Comment: @juanmirocks the tutorial says so, but in practice there's an error (`v4.2.0`) that `write got an unexpected keyword argument: pretty_print`

Comment: I think et.write doesn't exist anymore

Comment: you can also get a real python `str` by using `etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode")`. See [lxml.etree.tostring API doc](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.tostring)

Comment: @mokko this is lxml which has added to ElementTree it is in https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.tostring

Comment: Can someone please explain the thinking behind whether to write binary or not?  There are 4 variations in the answers: write using 'w' or 'wb' and writing the tree directly or using tree.tostring().

Comment: @John that is a seperate question. However in this case note my edit re Python 2 and 3. One of the main differences between them is are you dealing with bytes  or text whic needs an encoding. I think lxml write does it all for you. Try the code and ignore the comments for the moment. Then comment if it does not work

Comment: Thanks @mmmmmm -- I had forgotten about Python 2.

Comment: There is an issue described here https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/786 that `sys.stdout.buffer` might not exist.   What should the first argument of `write` be to print the xml to stdout?

Comment: @JimNewton  It needs to be a file object which is something that has a write method - This looks like it is Juypter specific and a separate question

Comment: No, not jupiter specific.  I have the same problem elsewhere and I see that the problem also seems to exist in jupyter, although I don't understand jupyter, so I can't verify.

Comment: @JimNewton As I said I think that is a new question - but in your case what is the file object you are passing in and where does it come from

Answer (score 13):

You can try the below code.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.Element('Doc')
level1 = ET.SubElement(root, 'S')
main = ET.SubElement(level1, 'Text')
main.text = 'Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!'
second = ET.SubElement(level1, 'Tokens')
level2 = ET.SubElement(second, 'Token', word=u"low")


level3 = ET.SubElement(level2, 'Morph')
second1 = ET.SubElement(level3, 'Lemma')
second1.text = 'sdfs'
second1 = ET.SubElement(level3, 'info')
second1.text = 'qw'

level4 = ET.SubElement(level3, 'Aff')
second1 = ET.SubElement(level4, 'Type')
second1.text = 'sdfs'
second1 = ET.SubElement(level4, 'Suf')
second1.text = 'qw'

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,   encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a succinct answer

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("root")
root.set("interesting", "somewhat")
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, "test")

my_tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
with open('./filename', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(my_tree))
```

you simply place your node in a new tree and write that out to disk. Also works for `HtmlElements` produced by xpath searches.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
et = etree.ElementTree(document)
with open('sample.xml', 'wb') as f:
    et.write(f, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give the filename to the `write()` of ElementTree

```
etree.ElementTree(root).write('output.xml')
```